# Как удалить или просто скрыть картинку при клике на крестик?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как скрыть блок `.con_img` с картинкой после клика на крестик `.clear_buton`

```css
.con_img {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  background: #FFD140;
  border: 1px solid #FFC000;
  padding: 0px;
  width: 150px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5x;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 20px;
}
.img {
  width: 140px;
  max-height: 100px;
  float: left;
  margin: 0px 0px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  padding: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
}
.clear_buton {
  position: absolute;
  right: -12px;
  top: -12px;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 10;
}
.clear_buton:hover {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, .9);
}
```

```html
<br>
<b>Картинки взяты из интернета для примера</b>
<br>
<br>


<div class="con_img">
  <div class="qwer">
    <img src="http://www.veryicon.com/icon/48/System/Must%20Have/Remove.png" alt="Remove" class="clear_buton" title="Удалить" width="30" height="30" />
    <img src="http://tn.new.fishki.net/20/preview/1270796.jpg" class="img" />
  </div>
</div>


<div class="con_img">
  <div class="qwer">
    <img src="http://www.veryicon.com/icon/48/System/Must%20Have/Remove.png" alt="Remove" class="clear_buton" title="Удалить" width="30" height="30" />
    <img src="http://72.img.avito.st/640x480/444007172.jpg" class="img" />
  </div>
</div>



<div class="con_img">
  <div class="qwer">
    <img src="http://www.veryicon.com/icon/48/System/Must%20Have/Remove.png" alt="Remove" class="clear_buton" title="Удалить" width="30" height="30" />
    <img src="http://file.mobilmusic.ru/db/3b/8f/681628-240.jpg" class="img" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JQuery. Код для удаления. Для скрытия в коде ниже надо соответственно вместо remove подставить hide.

```
$(".clear_buton").click(function(event){
    $(this).closest(".con_img").remove();
});
```